# Transforming a cumulative sequence of values by date to the non cumulative values

Tags: mysql

Is it possible with mysql, to get the sum for a given date range of cumulative values?

Assume data are like this (cumulative week starting on Saturday -Day column is not needed , just there to show the change and easier to visualize):

```
Date       Day         Value
03/11/2016 Thursday    15
04/11/2016 Friday      18
05/11/2016 Saturday     4
06/11/2016 Sunday       6
07/11/2016 Monday       8
08/11/2016 Tuesday     10
09/11/2016 Wednesday   13
10/11/2016 Thursday    17
11/11/2016 Friday      18
12/11/2016 Saturday     2
13/11/2016 Sunday       4
14/11/2016 Monday       6
and so on...
```

So for example If I was asking for the result from 03/11/2016 to 04/11/2016 I would expect to see : 3 (18-15)
from 03/11/2016 to 07/11/2016 : (18-15)+4+(6-4)+(8-6) = 11

or to put it better the above table should be transformed to :

```
Date       Day         Value
03/11/2016 Thursday     -
04/11/2016 Friday       3
05/11/2016 Saturday     4
06/11/2016 Sunday       2
07/11/2016 Monday       2
08/11/2016 Tuesday      2
09/11/2016 Wednesday    3
10/11/2016 Thursday     4
11/11/2016 Friday       1
12/11/2016 Saturday     2
13/11/2016 Sunday       2
14/11/2016 Monday       2
```

In php or other languages I would just go like (pseudocode):

```
If (day != Saturday) {value = currentvalue-yesterdayvalue} else {value = currentvalue)
```

Ideally I would like to derive this one in mysql

Comment: Using [mySQL User Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) I would believe this would be possible.  you'd use a case statement to check for Saturday and reinitialize the variable back to the base value.  Every time after that you'd be taking the new value less the base value.  you may need a 2nd variable to store the prior records original value.

Comment: According to your example, there is one additional rule: If the value of the current day is less than that of the previous, present it as-is (see the case of 05/11/2016). Am I right?

Comment: That's because on saturday the values are reset, so whatever is on saturday stays as it is. the values are cumulative waste for some sales data.  there is no way that the current day value will be less than yesterday's, except if it is Saturday.

Comment: Basically to find the value for a day you just subtract from the previous one, except if it saturday where you subtract 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(x.date) = 5 
            THEN x.value 
            ELSE x.value-y.value END x 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.date = x.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```